# create angular object from text input label and value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to bind a number of textboxes to a `$scope` object. However, I need it to put the value as an object with a very specific structure.

Plunker available [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jb3lywT0nqtGRz6CxFw3?p=preview).

The desired result is to push objects with the following structure:

```
[{
"Params": [{
    "childParam": "3", <-- text-input value
    "param": "Sets"    <-- Param value (also text-input label)
}, {
    "childParam": "9", <-- text-input value
    "param": "Reps"    <-- Param value (also text-input label)
}]
```

**My question is what do I need my `ng-model` to be in order to bind the input to my object and create the above structure.**

Here are my Param

```
$scope.Params = [{
    "param": "Sets"
}, {
    "param": "Reps"
}, {
    "param": "Weight"
}, {
    "param": "Color"
}, {
    "param": "TimeSec"
}, {
    "param": "TimeMin"
}, {
    "param": "Hold"
}, {
    "param": "Tempo"
}];
```

Here are my text inputs

```
<label ng-repeat="value in Params" class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">{{value.param}}</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="exercise.Params.test[value.param]" placeholder="John">
</label>
```

Comment: You should make your plunkr a mcve: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve it contains two ng-repeats and is different to your question.

Comment: Try it ```ng-model="exercise.Params[$index][value.param]"```

Comment: @Thomas I believe it is important to have the two `ng-repeat`s because of how `$index` behaves.

Comment: And this if you want to use childParam as model ```ng-model="exercise.Params[$index].childParam"```

Comment: Close Alexander, however this doesn't create the same structure I require.